# Where are PEM files stored for validating SSL certificates?

Tags: 12.04, ssl, openssl

I'm writing a SOAP client application on Ubuntu using OpenSSL and C++. I am having trouble getting my code to validate the server certificate even though I know has a valid certificate.

Just to make sure I would like to check that it's the case and apparently PEM files are used to list valid certificates.

Can anyone tell me where these files reside on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation? I have the ca-certificates package installed on my machine, so these files must be there somewhere?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So if you have installed `ca-certificates` you can easily find out where the files are. Open a terminal and enter

```
> dpkg -L ca-certificates
/.
/etc
/etc/ssl
/etc/ssl/certs
/etc/ca-certificates
/etc/ca-certificates/update.d
/usr
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
/usr/share
/usr/share/ca-certificates
/usr/share/ca-certificates/spi-inc.org
…
```

So you'll see that all certificates are in `/usr/share/ca-certificates`. However the default location for certificates is `/etc/ssl/certs`. You might find additional certificates there.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

`sudo find / |grep "\.pem"`

This will list all the `.pem` files present on your system and their full path.

Comment: This is not really an answer.

Comment: Not an answer but very useful! Thanks @Mausy5043 for posting this.

Comment: sudo is probably unnecessary, since these files needn't be hidden. Also, find can itself test name parameters, so I recommend `find / -name "*.pem"`

Comment: @sondra.kinsey : `find`ing upwards from `/` without using `sudo` will generate a lot of errors for directories that the user has no access to. Using `sudo` (or redirecting by adding `2> /dev/null` keeps the output clean.

Answer (score 3):

Probably this would help you:

`apt-get install apt-file`

`apt-file update`

`apt-file list ca-certificates`