# No certificate files inside of /usr/lib/ssl

Tags: ssl, wget, openssl, certificates

I don't appear to have any SSL certs installed on my machine and it is causing issues with wget and Faraday called within Rails.

When I run `openssl version -a` I am told my `OPENSSLDIR` is  `"/usr/lib/ssl"`.

When I look inside `/usr/lib/ssl/certs` it is empty.

When I run `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates` I am told that ca-certificates is already at the newest version and when I run `sudo update-ca-certificates` I get the following output;

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
There was a problem saving the new Java keystore. Message:
  /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts (No such file or directory)
E: /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with code 1.
done.
```

I have two questions.

1) Am I barking up the wrong tree? Is it normal for `/usr/lib/ssl/certs` to be empty

2) What is the next step I should take?

### Update

When I run `dpkg -L ca-certificates` (Thanks to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183328/where-are-pem-files-stored-for-validating-ssl-certificates?rq=1)) I can see plenty of mozilla certs stored in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/`

Comment: What happens when you create the folder /etc/ssl/certs/java/ and re-run the update-ca-certificates command?

Comment: @psynnott good thinking, that seemed to allow it to populate! If you want to add this as an answer I can mark as the accepted solution

Comment: I don't pretend to fully understand the purpose of each of the folders you mentioned, I just took a stab at what the command was trying to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that if you create the folder `/etc/ssl/certs/java/`, it will allow the `sudo update-ca-certificates` to complete.  It looks like it just isn't able to create the file because it's parent folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Some observations about this in 16.04.06 LTS (vintage of the OP): openssl reports "/usr/lib/ssl", which is where 'openssl.cnf' lives, but "/usr/lib/ssl/certs" is just a symbolic link to "etc/ssl/certs".  On top of that, all of the many certs (pem, crt, etc) are symbolic links to "/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla".  O.o Yet the issue here was a java folder.  It seems the openssl root of trust is some mash-up of java and mozilla trust models.